# AWS error message: {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

i have build lambda function and api gateway.
its working fine when I am testing it from API gateway however it not working when using invoke URL generated once it deployed.

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Invoke URL accepts query string.

any idea on the error message?

Comment: What is the Invoking URL ??

Comment: Make sure you add the resource in your URL

Comment: this is the invoke url: https://kbe5snf1pi.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Dev/calc/1/2/+  , cant i send just parameters ?

Comment: `+` is this the resource name ?

Comment: calc is the resource name and 1,2,+ are the querystrings.

Comment: this looks okay to me, not sure, do u think there is no typo in the URL . Also  Please make sure you're using the correct HTTP method (GET or POST ) and resource path to a valid resource

Comment: @NishantSingh . If am using this invoke url: https://kbe5snf1pi.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Dev/calc?operand2=4&operator=/&operand1=7   it is working.Is there is a way we just send parameters to invoke the function.Like Dev/calc/1/2/+ instead of sending operand2=4&operator=/&operand1=7  ?